# What are the criteria for Open Graph Insights to begin showing up?

Tags: analytics, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

Our app, popularise.com added publishing of open graph actions a few weeks ago and I do see referrals coming from FB as a result of these actions but the insights on developers.facebook.com only shows the "Looks like you haven't started publishing to the Open Graph yet!" message.

My question is what is the criteria for the open graph insights to begin showing up?  Is there a certain number of actions that need to be published?  Or a certain amount in a specific time period?

Answer (score 3):

For my application, the open graph analytics started showing almost instantaneously after my action was approved and our users started posting them to Facebook.

However since this morning, the open graph insights for my app says "Looks like you haven't started publishing to the Open Graph yet!". So I suspect that some sort of a bug must have creeped in very recently.

Comment: We're seeing the same thing across several apps.

Comment: Open Graph insights seem to be back up for my app.